# Transform class text to my domain name without http and www

Tags: javascript, jquery, subdomain, no-www

Using jquery or any script, how to change Text inside semantic `<p>` and `<h1>` with class='site-title' on my `<header/>` to my domain name without `http://`, `www.` and permalink path.

Source:

```
<header role='banner'>
<h1 class='site-title'>My Blog Title</h1><!-- homepage header title -->
<p class='site-title'><a href='mylink'>My Blog Title</a></p><!-- other page header title -->
</header>
```

**TO** (if blog is using sub-domain):

```
<header role='banner'>
    <h1 class='site-title'>mysubdomain.blogspot.com</h1><!-- change the text My Blog Title only -->
    <p class='site-title'><a href='mylink'>mysubdomain.blogspot.com</a></p><!-- get my domain name witout http and www -->
    </header>
```

**OR** (if blog using self domain - not sub-domain):

```
<header role='banner'>
    <h1 class='site-title'>blogspot.com</h1>
    <p class='site-title' href='mylink'>blogspot.com</p>
    </header>
```

Comment: see http://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.site-title').text(window.location.host);
});
```

Where the text of h1 and p will be replaced by the current url of the page.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XBKW3/1/)

Comment: @DavidThomas You're right, it is a quick answer and i didn't optimize it. I edit my answer.

Comment: You now have a typo in your class-selector., missing the period.

Comment: i have problerm, how to filter `www`?

Comment: ok done `var site = location.hostname.replace(/^www\./,''); $('h1.site-title').text( site );
$('p.site-title a').text( site );`

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like that with jquery:

```
    var myDomain = window.location.host;
    $(".site-title").html(myDomain);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var site = location.hostname.replace(/^www\./,'');
$('.site-title').text( site );
```